# Azure Event Hub - Alias vs Regional Endpoint?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have deployed the same Java spring boot application in both WEST US and East US.

At any point, either WEST US or East US will be active and other one will be passive meaning the application should not read the By default, West US will be active.

I have enabled Geo Replication for the Event Hub.

In case of manual failover, East US will become active and start reading the Event Hub and West US will go passive.

Now that I have setup the Geo Replication for the Event Hub. It has 3 endpoints

1. West US
2. East US
3. Alias

Which endpoint should I use to connect with the Event Hub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always use alias endpoint all the times. Alias DNS initially resolves to primary namespace endpoint. When failover is complete, alias DNS will start resolving to secondary namespace endpoint thereby eliminating the need for changes in client configuration.

Comment: Where do I Check the current primary and secondary namespace endpoint? Is secondary will always be read only? If not, how to make it read only?

Comment: Yes, secondary is always read only until the failover. Again, clients don't need to know about primary and secondary endpoints.Allias namespace or the connection string is the only thing clients will need.